# Using dynamic methods to build SQL queries in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using this class as Modal in my CodeIgniter project, as I'm newbie in CI, I wanna know if this has some issues, I'm using this modal for all queries, like I call this with parameters and it returns results as I wanted. But I'm not sure if it a good idea or it might give some bad impact to structure and security.

```
<?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  class Crud extends CI_Model {
      public function Read($TableName, $Condition) {
          if ($Condition == '')
              $Condition = ' 1';
          $this->db->where($Condition);
          $data = $this->db->get($TableName);
          return $data->result();
      }
      public function Create($data, $TableName) {
          if ($this->db->insert($data, $TableName))
              return $this->db->insert_id();
          else
              return false;
      }
      public function Update($TableName, $Fields, $Condition) {
          if ($Condition == '')
              $Condition = ' 1';
          $this->db->where($Condition);
          if ($this->db->update($TableName, $Fields))
              return true;
          else
              return false;
      }
      public function Delete($TableName, $Condition) {
          if ($Condition == '')
              $Condition = ' 1';
          $this->db->where($Condition);
          if ($this->db->delete($TableName))
              return true;
          else
              return false;
      }
      public function Count($TableName, $Condition) {
          if ($Condition == '')
              $Condition = ' 1';
          $this->db->where($Condition);
          $result = $this->db->get($TableName);
          if ($result)
              return $result->num_rows();
          else
              return false;
      }
```

I call this methods like this in my controller

```
public function changeStatus() {
   $tableName = $this->uri->segment(4);
   $status = $this->uri->segment(5);
   $conditionId = $this->uri->segment(6);
   $condition = " `id` = '$conditionId'";
   $data = [
       'is_active' => $status
   ];
   if($this->Crud->Update($tableName, $data, $condition))
       $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "Success! Changes saved");
   else
       $this->session->set_flashdata('danger', "Something went wrong");
   $referer = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
   redirect('admin/seller/'.$referer);
}
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In accordance with [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/), your method names should be in camelCase. To avoid function name conflicts (native `count()` with custom `count()`), it may be best to prefix the method names' functionality with `easy` or `simple`, `ci`, or `ar` for Active Record.

"Embrace the curly brace."  Always use curly braces to encapsulate your language construct and function bodies -- even if they only have one line of code inside them.  Not using `{` and `}` may lead to developer confusion or unintended/incorrect code logic.

For versatility, I recommend passing an array of arrays to your Crud methods.  This will allow you to separate column names from values, enable you to turn off CI's automatic quoting (`protect_identifiers` flag) when necessary (3rd element in a respective subarray), and effortlessly pass multiple where conditions when required.  There is a multitude of reasons for this utility -- here is just one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2489453/2943403.

Granted, your `Read()` method _could_be as simple as passing the table name and an associative array of conditions to `get_where()`, but that approach doesn't permit the flexibility of turning off the auto-quoting.

Make the default `$condition` parameter value an empty array.  I don't like the meaningless `WHERE 1` in any project.

Use a foreach loop to only add a WHERE clause when there is actually something useful to write inside it.

```
public function ciRead($tableName, $conditions = []) {
    foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
        $this->db->where($condition);
    }
    $this->db->get($tableName)->result();
}
```

`insert()` [should have the table name as the first parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3360631/2943403).

```
public function ciCreate($tableName, $data) {
    return $this->db->insert($tableName, $data) ? $this->db->insert_id() : false;
}
```

For `update()` loop the conditions like in `read()`  I recommend returning the affected rows so that there is a truer representation of success. I often treat the affected rows value as a boolean or explicitly cast it with `(bool)` if I only need a truthy/falsey value and I want to make the coding intention very clear.

```
public function ciUpdate($tableName, $data, $conditions = []) {
    foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
        $this->db->where($condition);
    }
    return $this->db->update($tableName, $data) ? $this->db->affected_rows() : false;
}
```

Same thinking with `delete()` regarding a more accurate return value...

```
public function ciDelete($tableName, $conditions = []) {
    foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
        $this->db->where($condition);
    }
    return $this->db->delete($tableName) ? $this->db->affected_rows() : false;
}
```

When counting, CI has `count_all_results()`.

```
public function ciCount($tableName, $conditions = []) {
    foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
        $this->db->where($condition);
    }
    return $this->db->count_all_results($tableName);
}
```

---

In your controller (assuming all of the routing is set up properly), you should be collecting the slash-delimited input values as parameters of the method call instead of writing out all of those `segment()` calls.

Using `$_GET` data is perfectly fine when calling your `Read()` or `Count()` methods, but it is not recommended when you are writing to the database.  For `Insert()`, `Update()`, and `Delete()`, you need to be collecting user-supplied data via `$_POST` data only.

Be sure to validate and sanitize the incoming data in your controller before allowing access to your model methods.

Don't give your users any more access/privilege than absolutely necessary.  I wouldn't be letting people know what my table or column names are called.   I wouldn't want to offer them the flexibility to nominate the table/column that they want to access -- purely on the grounds of security.

Perhaps provide some kind of alias/whitelist to convert the user data to model entity identifiers (translate the table/column names with in the model) or ideally make all of the table/column names static/hardcoded (provided by you, the developer).

```
public function fetch($tableName, $conditionId) {
    $result = $this->Crud->ciRead($tableName, [['id', $conditionId]]));
    ...
}
```

or when writing to the db use `post()`.

```
public function changeStatus() {
    $tableName = $this->input->post('tableName');  // I don't like it
    $status = $this->input->post('status');
    $conditionId $this->input->post('conditionId');
    if ($this->Crud->ciUpdate($tableName, ['is_active' => $status], [['id', $conditionId]])) {
       $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "Success! Changes saved");
    } else {
       $this->session->set_flashdata('danger', "Something went wrong");
    }
    redirect('admin/seller/' . basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
}
```